# Reliable way to write to a channel when buffer available

Tags: go, select, channel, goroutine

I've been working on a sort-of pub-sub mechanism in the application we're building. The business logic basically generates a whack-ton of events, which in turn can be used to feed data to the client using API's, or persistent in storage if the application is running with that option enabled.

### What we had, and observed:

Long story short, it turns out we were dropping data we really ought not to have been dropping. The *"subscriber"* had a channel with a large buffer, and essentially only read data from this channel, checked a few things, and appended it to a slice. The capacity of the slice is such that memory allocations were kept to a minimum. Simulating a scenario where the subscriber channel had a buffer of, say, 1000 data-sets, we noticed data could be dropping after only 10 sets being sent. The very first event was never dropped.

The code we had at this point looks something like this:

```
type broker struct {
    ctx  context.Context
    subs []*sub
}

type sub struct {
    ctx context.Context
    mu  *sync.Mutex
    ch  chan []interface{}
    buf []interface{}
}

func (b *broker) Send(evts ...interface{}) {
    rm := make([]int, 0, len(b.subs))
    defer func() {
        for i := len(rm) - 1; i >= 0; i-- {
            // last element
            if i == len(b.subs)-1 {
                b.subs = b.subs[:i]
                continue
            }
            b.subs = append(b.subs[:i], b.subs[i+1:]...)
        }
    }()
    for i, s := range b.subs {
        select {
        case <-b.ctx.Done(): // is the app still running
            return
        case <-s.Stopped(): // is this sub still valid
            rm = append(rm, i)
        case s.C() <- evts: // can we write to the channel
            continue
        default: // app is running, sub is valid, but channel is presumably full, skip
            fmt.Println("skipped some events")
        }
    }
}

func NewSub(ctx context.Context, buf int) *sub {
    s := &sub{
        ctx: ctx,
        mu:  &sync.Mutex{},
        ch:  make(chan []interface{}, buf),
        buf: make([]interface{}, 0, buf),
    }
    go s.loop(ctx) // start routine to consume events
    return s
}

func (s *sub) C() chan<- []interface{} {
    return s.ch
}

func (s *sub) Stopped() <-chan struct{} {
    return s.ctx.Done()
}

func (s *sub) loop(ctx context.Context) {
    defer func() {
        close(s.ch)
    }()
    for {
        select {
        case <-ctx.Done():
            return
        case data := <-s.ch:
            // do some processing
            s.mu.Lock()
            s.buf = append(s.buf, data...)
            s.mu.Unlock()
        }
    }
}

func (s *sub) GetProcessedData(amt int) []*wrappedT {
    s.mu.Lock()
    data := s.buf
    if len(data) == amt {
        s.buf = s.buf[:0]
    } else if len(data) > amt {
        data = data[:amt]
        s.buf = s.buf[amt:]
    } else {
        s.buf = make([]interface{}, 0, cap(s.buf))
    }
    s.mu.Unlock()
    ret := make([]*wrappedT, 0, len(data))
    for _, v := range data {
        // some processing
        ret = append(ret, &wrappedT{v})
    }
    return ret
}
```

Now obviously, the buffers are there to ensure that events can still be consumed when we're calling things like `GetProcessedData`. That type of call is usually the result of an API request, or some internal flush/persist to storage mechanism. Because of the mutex lock, we might not be reading from the internal channel. Weirdly, the channel buffers never got backed up all the way through, but not all data made its way through to the subscribers. As mentioned, the first event always did, which made us even more suspicious.

### What we eventually tried (to fix):

After a fair bit of debugging, hair pulling, looking at language specs, and fruitless googling I began to suspect the `select` statement to be the problem. Instead of sending to the channels directly, I changed it to the rather hacky:

```
func (b *broker) send(s *sub, evts []interface{}) {
    ctx, cfunc := context.WithTimeout(b.ctx, 100 *time.Millisecond)
    defer cfunc()
    select {
    case <-ctx:
        return
    case sub.C() <- evts:
        return
    case <-sub.Closed():
        return
    }
}

func (b *broker) Send(evts ...interface{}) {
    for _, s := range b.subs {
         go b.send(s, evts)
    }
}
```

Instantly, all events were correctly propagated through the system. Calling `Send` on the broker wasn't blocking the part of the system that actually performs the heavy lifting (that was the reason for the use of channels after all), and things are performing reasonably well.

### The actual question(s):

There's a couple of things still bugging me:

1. The way I read the specs, the default statement ought to be the last resort, solely as a way out to prevent blocking channel operations in a select statement. Elsewhere, I read that the runtime may not consider a case ready for communication if there is no routine consuming what you're about to write to the channel, irrespective of channel buffers. Is this indeed how it works?
2. For the time being, the context with timeout fixes the bigger issue of data not propagating properly. However, I do feel like there should be a better way.
3. Has anyone ever encountered something similar, and worked out exactly what's going on?

---

I'm happy to provide more details where needed. I've kept the code as minimal as possible, omitting a lot of complexities WRT the broker system we're using (different event types, different types of subscribers, etc...). We don't use the `interface{}` type anywhere in case anyone is worried about that :P

For now, though, I think this is plenty of text for a Friday.

Comment: In your example here, there is no reason for the `default` except to drop messages. The switch behavior is simple, the `default` case is taken if none of the other cases case proceed. It appears you've refactored this into a more complicated version of the same switch without the `default`.

Comment: @JimB: I mention it somewhere in the post, but we have optional and non-optional subscribers. Required ones have a blocking `sub.Push()` call, the optional ones ought to receive data over a channel, but we can skip it if the buffer is full (hence the default case). It's just that the default case seems to be selected even if the channel buffer is not full

Comment: The default case will not be selected if there is another runnable case at the time.

Comment: Was the `"skipped some events"` message displayed? Another possibility might be that the mutex is be being released too early in `GetProcessedData`. `data := s.buf` copies the slice but both still reference the same underlying array. Before `data` is ranged over, `s.buf` could have been written over by new events in the subscriber's loop function. Possible?

Comment: @Mark Yes, the `skipped some events` message is unfortunately logged all too often. Releasing the mutex too early I think would've shown up when we run `go test -count=1 -race -v` step in the CI, especially considering we've got unit tests covering just about any outlandish case we could think of (including app context closing while streams are connected/removed while events are multiplexed etc...). It does look like we're just getting the default case because the read-routine isn't actually reading, regardless of buffer. I'll update with a more representative example later perhaps

Comment: @Adrian: That's exactly what I thought, but the thing that we're finding ourselves wondering now is just how _"runnable"_ is determined. The spec says: _"If one or more of the communications can proceed, a single one that can proceed is chosen"_. If a channel is buffered, writing to the channel may be possible, but if there's no routine currently reading, it seems that writing to an unread channel is not seen as communication, and thus `default` is selected. If we assume this is the case, we end up with the timeout routine, and everything works...

Comment: That is definitely not the case. A write to a buffered channel that is not full constitutes a communication that can proceed regardless of whether there's a reader. This is easily demonstrated: https://play.golang.org/p/QKibC4i7Kza